# java code for testing command line args in range of 1-5

Tags: java

I am tring to do `if()` for `String[] args` to check if the string is between 1 to 5

here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(args[0] == "1" || args[0] == "2" || args[0] == "3" || args[0] == "4" || args[0] == "5");
}
```

the code is returning false when I type anything.

thx for help

Comment: You should use `.equals` and not `==` to compare Strings.

Comment: Well, to check if a string contains numeric 1 - 15 from args[], you might need to define a separate function.